# Issues with Text Fractions (⅛, ⅜, etc.)

Tags: r, text

For this HTML table I'm using:

```
library("XML")

combine.2014 = readHTMLTable("http://mockdraftable.com/players/2014/", header=T, which=1,stringsAsFactors=F)
```

I'm trying to convert text fractions like "9⅛" to 9.125

I cannot seem to get R to identify the fraction portion of this text. I've tried both

```
combine.2014$Arms2 <- ifelse(is.na(str_locate(string=combine.2014$Arms, '⅛')[,1]) == TRUE, 0, 0.125)

combine.2014$Arms2 <- ifelse(is.na(str_locate(string=combine.2014$Arms, 'â.>')[,1]) == TRUE, 0, 0.125)
```

It works for the fractions ¼, ½, ¾ but not ⅛, ⅜, ⅝, and ⅞.

Comment: This is going to be because ¼, ½, ¾ are defined in the Latin Windows ANSI code pages, but ⅛, ⅜, ⅝, and ⅞ are not.

Comment: Thanks David. So does that mean there's nothing I can do?

Comment: Add the parameter `encoding="UTF-8"` to your `readHTMLTable` statement.

Comment: In a properly formatted HTML document the encoding should be inferred from the document, not provided externally. Can you show us how the document looks like, and what header is sent by the server?

Comment: Hi Konrad, and thanks for the help, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: @FrankB. You can use a service such as http://web-sniffer.net/ to get the response header. The relevant field is the `Content-Type`. That should be set to the relevant encoding. If it isn’t, the encoding specified inside the HTML document is used. If *that* is missing too, the XML library will use the `encoding` you provide via a parameter, as specified by lukeA (however, to emphasise, this is a *bad* solution. HTML resources *should* already specify an encoding).

Comment: OK, I'm not sure if this is what you need but here's what I ran:

Comment: > getEncoding(xmlParse(url))
Opening and ending tag mismatch: meta line 6 and head
Opening and ending tag mismatch: tr line 85 and thead
Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
Bytes: 0x97 0x50 0x75 0x65
Opening and ending tag mismatch: thead line 84 and table
Opening and ending tag mismatch: table line 83 and div
Entity 'copy' not defined
Opening and ending tag mismatch: div line 28 and body
Opening and ending tag mismatch: body line 27 and html
Premature end of data in tag meta line 5
Premature end of data in tag head line 3
Premature end of data in tag html line 2

Comment: @KonradRudolph, I used your suggestion and got Content-Type: text/html. With a bit more Google-ing it seems this is in "HTML Entity (decimal)" format. Does that sound right? I am a SQL guy and not overly familiar with HTML/XML.

Comment: @FrankB. Not sure where you got the “decimal” from. The salient part is that no `charset` is specified. So far so good. So how does your document look like? It **should** have something along the lines of `<meta charset="something">` in its `<head>` section, but it probably doesn’t (otherwise you wouldn’t have the problem). As a consequence, the XML library assumes another encoding which you can override by providing the appropriate function argument. Only thing is, you need to *know* the encoding in order to do that.

Comment: @KonradRudolph You're right, no charset. This is what websnifer says: HTTP Request Header

Connect to 208.113.128.59 on port 80 ... ok

GET /players/2014/ HTTP/1.1[CRLF]
Host: mockdraftable.com[CRLF]
Connection: close[CRLF]
User-Agent: Web-sniffer/1.0.47 (+http://web-sniffer.net/)[CRLF]
Accept-Encoding: gzip[CRLF]
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,UTF-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7[CRLF]
Cache-Control: no-cache[CRLF]
Accept-Language: de,en;q=0.7,en-us;q=0.3[CRLF]
Referer: http://web-sniffer.net/[CRLF]
[CRLF]

Comment: (The request header is irrelevant here.)

Comment: OK, thanks all. I'm apparently in over my head so I'll just try some good ol' trial and error and hope the blind squirrel analogy applies to me.

Comment: I'm the guy that runs MockDraftable. If you want the data, just ask! No need to scrape. I store it in decimal form, and regularly export it for others, so it's not even a big ask.